# Compile a simple program on ubuntu arm

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, arm, glib

I have a simple program

```
#include <glib.h>
int main(){
  g_print("hallo\n");
}
```

and try to compile it on the embedded system (Odroid X2) with Ubuntu like that

```
root@odroid:~/# gcc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0) -o main main.c
/tmp/cci48ASK.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `g_print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Installed compiler:

```
root@odroid:~/x# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
```

Any ideas why the linker does not find the reference?

Comment: Your command worked exactly as-is for me on Fedora 18. I have `gcc` version 4.7.2. What is your version (your `gcc -v` output was cut off before the last line)?

Answer (score 4):

The order of options to `gcc` (and other compilers) *matters*.

```
gcc -Wall main.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0) -o main
```

And I don't really like the above. You should learn how to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). At the very least, put the compile flags, then the sources, then the object files, then the libraries (from high level to low level).

```
gcc -Wall $(pkg-config  --cflags glib-2.0) main.c \
    $(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0) -o main
```

Better yet, have a `Makefile` starting with

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall  $(pkg-config  --cflags glib-2.0) 
LIBES= $(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
```

And compiling as root should be avoided. Only installation should require root privilege...

You probably want to add `-g` (compiler flag for debugging information). Once the program is ready and nearly bugfree, replace it with `-O2` (optimizations) and do some serious testing again!

Comment: This is worth a shot, but I tried his command line as-is on Fedora 18 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found a solution

```
gcc -o main main.c  `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0`
```

works, but I don't know why on my X64 linux system it worked also the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `$(pgk-config --libs glib-2.0)` after the `main.c` in your compile line - because library functions are only dragged into the binary if there is anything using them - so main.c is what is using the `g_print`, and if the `-lglib` (or whatever the result of the `pkg-config` bit is) is before `main.c`, it doesn't get included in the resulting binary.