# About Makefile can't find libraries

Tags: opencv, makefile, g++

The **Exception** is here:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I./include -I. -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc main.o ColorTransfer.o
main.o: In function `showImg(std::string, cv::Mat, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
main.o: In function `main':
```

And the **Makefile** is here:

```
CC=g++
FLAGS=-L./lib -I./include -I. -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc

all: ColorTransfer

ColorTransfer: main.o ColorTransfer.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.o ColorTransfer.o -o ColorTransfer

main.o: main.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o

ColorTransfer.o: ColorTransfer.cpp ColorTransfer.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c ColorTransfer.cpp -o ColorTransfer.o

clean :
    rm -rf main.o ColorTransfer.o
```

And current directory contains directory named lib, which has opencv libraries.

Comment: `make` is doing what you *incorrectly* asked it to do. But `g++` is wrongly invoked in your `Makefile`; it is not `make` but `g++` which does not find libraries...

Answer (score 0):

In your folder:

```
 /lib
```

You have to be sure that there are:

```
 opencv_core.so
 opencv_highgui.so
 opencv_imgproc.so
```

And that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH point to this folder. Otherwise, you've to export it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib
```

Have you download opencv sources or precompiled? Have you configured dynamic linker run-time bindings?

```
sudo ldconfig
```

## edit

Otherwise, try to check [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816607/opencv-2-3-compiling-issue-undefined-refence-ubuntu-11-10) this soloution!

Comment: Thanks. yes, I have already run the code using IDE(Eclipse+CDT), but I want to compile code using Makefile. And I tried your suggestion, but it also not works.

Answer (score 0):

You really should pay attention to the order of arguments to `g++` ; it matters a lot (libraries should go last in good order - highest level to lowest level).

Use  `make -p` to learn about rules known to `make`.... Then improve your `Makefile` as follow

```
 CXX=g++
 CXXFLAGS= -I./include -I. -g -Wall
 LDLIBS= -L./lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc

 all: ColorTransfer

 ColorTransfer: main.o ColorTransfer.o
           $(LINK.cc)  $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

 # etc....
```

I leave you to correct the other lines of your `Makefile` ... See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18877584/841108) ...

<sup>I corrected my make rules above : `$^` has to be before `$(LDLIBS)` !</sup>

BTW, [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) is a nice tool to debug `Makefile`-s; for instance, with `remake -x`