# Makefile giving "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, makefile

So I just got through a bunch of compiler issues and finally make runs well for the most part, however now I am getting an error

```
g++  prog4.cc
g++ -o lextest prog4.o Lexer.o Token.o
g++: prog4.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [lextest] Error 1
```

This is my makefile

```
OBJ = prog4.o Lexer.o Token.o
LEXER = Lexer.cc Lexer.h
TOKEN = Token.cc Token.h
OPTS = -g -c -Wall -Werror

lextest: $(OBJ)
        g++ -o lextest $(OBJ)

prog4.o: prog4.cc $(LEXER) $(TOKEN)
        g++ $(OPTS) prog4.cc

Lexer.o: Lexer.cc Lexer.h
        g++ $(OPTS) Lexer.cc

Token.o: Token.cc Token.h
        g++ $(OPTS) Token.cc

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~
```

Can anyone see any obvious errors in the makefile or would this error be generated by an issue in prog4.cc?

Pretty new to C++, so I hope this is just some simple error that I can fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Is file prog4.o there after running your makefile? Plus, there is a little bug in your script in line: _g++ $(OTPS) prog4.cc_ - it should be **OPTS**

Comment: No prog4.o doesnt appear - doesnt the makefile create that file for me?

Comment: Yes, it should. Does target _prog4.o_ even finish with success? Now you should see some compilation error if any.

Comment: Can you post the make command with arguments, if any, that you ran?

Comment: `$(OTPS)` instead of `$(OPTS)` would do it: the command only produces `prog4.o` because of the `-c` option. The transcript you put at the beginning of your question shows that `g++  prog4.cc` was executed, with the missing options. Did you try again after fixing that?

Comment: Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108) example of ̀̀`Makefile` as an inspiration

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the -c and -o options to g++

```
g++ -c -o prog4.o $(OPTS) prog4.cc
```

Comment: OPTS already has -c option and mentioning -o is optional unless you want to change the name of the object file