# How to write simple generic build script for C++ project?

Tags: c++, build, build-process

I'm writing C++ project made of few files on Linux. The project have no subdirectories.

I wanted like to have some as simple as possible, generic build script.

By generic, I mean that I don't want to hardcode file names, so that when I put new `.cpp` file into project, I don't have to modify build script. It should find and compile all modyfied source files in current directory, and link object files into executable. Nothing more.

I don't care about tool you'll use, since I don't know any yet.

I don't want to learn a tool from basics to write something as simple as that. For now, I just need a code, I'll learn when I'll need something more fancy.

## What I tryed

### `make`:

```
a.out: %.o
    $(CXX) %.o

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -Wall -c %.cpp
```

with no success:

```
make: *** Brak reguł do zrobienia obiektu `%.o', wymaganego przez `a.out'. Stop.
```

my translation of this message:

```
make: *** No rules to make object `%.o', required by `a.out'. Stop.
```

Before someone will ask, I'll answer: yes, my makefile is indented with 1 tab, not with spaces.

`make -d` prints out 664 lines, so I won't paste it here.

### `scons`:

```
Program("main.cpp")
```

It's copyed from some StackOverflow answer, but it is definietly intended to build a executable from one source file, because I get linker errors when I want use it.

I ended us using bash:

```
g++ -Wall *.cpp
```

Simple. Does the job well... for now. I don't think it's elegant and I know it's probably inefficent, because it recompiles everything, even unmodyfied files.

Comment: about **scons**: `Program(Glob("*.cpp"))` will build executable from all *.cpp files in a directory. In general, SCons is just a Python extension, so you are able to use Python power into your build system.

Comment: @Nevermore: thank you, it answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SRC := $(wildcard src/*.c)
DEP := $(SRC:src/%.c=lib/%.d)
OBJ := $(SRC:src/%.c=lib/%.o)
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -O2 -MMD

# Executable
lib/mines: lib/assets.o $(OBJ)
    ${CC} $^ -o $@

# Object files
lib/%.o:: src/%.c
    ${CC} -c $< -o $@ ${CFLAGS}

# Dependencies
# http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/
-include $(DEP)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm lib/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you have a directory full of single-source C++ programs (e.g. each program has one single C++ source file) named `.cpp` (e.g. `foo.cpp` & `bar.cpp`), each *independently* compiled to an executable (e.g. `foo` & `bar`). You might try the following (untested) `Makefile` for GNU `make`.

```
CXX= g++
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g -O
RM= rm -vf

SOURCES= $(wildcard *.cpp)
BINARIES= $(patsubst %.cpp, %, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINARIES)

clean:
     $(RM) *~ *.o $(BINARIES)
```

Read the [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and try `make -p` to find the builtin rules. See also these two examples of `Makefile`-s: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108)

If on the contrary you want one single executable `myprogram` from all the `*.cpp` files (like `foo.cpp` & `bar.cpp` etc....), you still can use `$(wildcard *.cpp)` in your `Makefile` (and you'll better not name `a.out` your executable, but something more meaningful), something like (in *addition* of common stuff like `CXXFLAGS=` above):

```
SOURCES= $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS= $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
all: myprogram
myprogram: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK.cc) $^ -o $@ $(LIBES)
```

In all cases, using `$(wildcard *.cpp)` is enough to have a `Makefile` generic enough on the list of sources. You may want to generate autodependencies (using `gcc -M` things, to some of *your* header files), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025816/841108).

Notice that you might have some C++ source or header files generated by some other means (e.g. your own `awk` or `python` script, or a `_timestamp.c` file generated with `date`, or some C++ files produced by a code generator like GNU [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/), etc, etc...). Then you need to add *specific* rules into your `Makefile`.

<sup>So in practice, I don't believe in *fully generic* build files, but I am trying to show you that a `Makefile` can be *almost* generic and short. At some time you'll adapt it to your particular needs.</sup>