# GCC Linux C - Compile object header not found

Tags: c, linux, object, gcc, header

I've been working on a module in C (under Linux) that requires another module (headers are in other directories).
My problem is that when I compile the code with my Makefile, the gcc compiler tells me that some headers aren't found.

```
gcc -c render.c
```

So I include the directories to find the header but here, gcc tries to find the "main" function which does not exist: it is a module...

```
gcc /opt/vc/include -c render.c
```

So I would like to know how is it possible to compile a module (output in module.o) that requires other modules?

Here are my files:

### render.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "render.h"

int width,height;
int loop,counter;

int initRender(void(*setup)(void),void(*draw)(void),void(*end)(void))
{
    init(&width, &height);
    loop = -1;
    counter = 0;

    setup();
    while(loop==-1)
    {
        Start(width, height);
        draw();
        End();
        counter++;
    }
    end();
    finish();
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

### render.h:

```
#include "VG/openvg.h"
#include "VG/vgu.h"
#include "fontinfo.h"
#include "shapes.h"

#ifndef RENDER_H_
#define RENDER_H_
extern int width,height;
extern int loop,counter;

int initRender(void(*setup)(void),void(*draw)(void),void(*end)(void));

#endif
```

### Makefile:

```
INCLUDEFLAGS=-I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -IopenVG
LIBFLAGS=-L/opt/vc/lib -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lbcm_host -lpthread  -ljpeg -LopenVG
NEEDED= openVG/libshapes.o openVG/oglinit.o

all: render

render.o:   render.c
    gcc -Wall -g $(INCLUDEFLAGS) -c render.c
```

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of a library (modules don't really exist in C)

Comment: You should edit your question and improve it: use the correct terminology (*module* is probably wrong) and give the *exact* commands and error messages. Also, take time to read the appropriate documentation.

Comment: BTW, you really should take time to read the documentation. It is much faster (and perhaps more polite) than asking here. My answer give several useful links.

Comment: Ok no problem, thanck you for your time Basile ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want

```
 gcc -Wall -g -I/opt/vc/include -c render.c
```

this will produce a `render.o` object file.

Please take time to **read the documentation about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)**. In particular, check what every option `-Wall`, `-g`, `-I` and `-c` means. IMHO the first two are *very important*.

Later, you probably want to link all your object files into an executable, with some external libraries. Perhaps you want something like

```
 gcc -g -Wall -L/opt/vc/lib render.o main.o -lvc -o myprogram
```

<sup>(you **really want** the `-Wall` and `-g` options; IMHO you need to be an expert to dare avoiding them; once you have debugged your program and want to benchmark it, add `-O2` for optimizations)</sup>

But surely, you want other options.

Notice that **order of arguments to `gcc` matters a *lot***

Of course, you should **learn about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)** and you need to use it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) examples. You might use `make --trace` (with recent `make`) or [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile` (which is not good). You should also run once `make -p`  to understand more the builtin rules of `make`.

Perhaps you want a library, then read the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

Comment: Thanck you Basile for your answer, in fact I knew that using the -I/../ would help me to include my directorys but I need 4 of them like:
gcc -I/opt/vc/include -IopenVG -c render.c
But here gcc talks me about main not being there...

Comment: Please don't include options that do not work towards the thing OP tries to achieve (`-Wall -g`). Too often I've seen people copy-pasting command lines from Stack Overflow without understanding what they mean.

Comment: I strongly disagree: beginners should *always* use `-Wall -g` and most experts also *almost always* use them (there are *rare* cases where you don't want them when you develop some code). I did however invite the OP to *read the documentation* to understand what they means.