# OpenCV cannot compile in custom directory

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I am on Ubuntu and want to install a different version of OpenCV(2.4.13) on a custom directory. I followed this tutorial here: http://code.litomisky.com/2014/03/09/how-to-have-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library-side-by-side/

I cannot get this simple main.cpp program to compile. I cannot create a cv::Mat image, but I can obtain the OpenCV version just fine!:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/version.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
std::cout << "OpenCV version: "
        << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << "." 
        << CV_MINOR_VERSION << "."
        << CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION
        << std::endl;

cv::Mat image; //without this line, it works!


return 0;
}
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CPP = g++ -std=c++0x

# OpenCV 2.4.13
CPPFLAGS = -L/home/myname/Desktop/myfolder/rewrite/opencv-2.4.13/release/installed/lib  \
           -I/home/myname/Desktop/myfolder/rewrite/opencv-2.4.13/release/installed/include


all: test

test: main.cpp
     $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

This is the compiler error:

```
/tmp/ccyrdd7H.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[cv::Mat::~Mat()]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccyrdd7H.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Makefile` is wrong. The `-L` & `-l` options are relevant at link time (but *not* at compile time). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) answers and examples (both quite similar to your question, and showing a `Makefile` that you should be able to adapt). Run `make -p` to understand the builtin rules and variables used by them.

<sup>(I am guessing you are on Linux)</sup>

Read more about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) & [dynamic linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), etc.. See Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

BTW, `CV_MAJOR_VERSION` etc... is probably a [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) defined in some header (mentioned by some of your [`#include` directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)). But `cv::Mat` is probably some genuine C++ class, with a constructor or a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which is referenced at link time.

Perhaps you should also read a good book about C++, e.g. [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/); but we don't have time and space to explain all that here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Why is it that I can obtain the version number with this makefile, but I cannot make a cv::Mat with the exact same makefile?

Comment: Which `Makefile` are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The makefile should be as so:

```
CPP = g++ -std=c++0x

# OpenCV trunk
CPPFLAGS = -L/home/myname/Desktop/myfolder/rewrite/opencv-2.4.13/release/installed/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc  \
           -I/home/myname/Desktop/myfolder/rewrite/opencv-2.4.13/release/installed/include

all: test

test: main.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

The flags -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc were missing.

With installation of opencv in a different directory, you may come up with a shared library error that cannot be accessed. In such cases follow the instructions here: [openCV program compile error "libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" in ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f)