# Getting Started with C development and GTK+

Tags: gcc, gtk

I'm really a Python developer exclusively, but I'm making my first foray into C programming now, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting started. I can't seem to get the hang of compilation and including libraries. At this point, I'm just identifying the libraries that I need and trying to compile them with a basic "hello, world" app just to make sure that I have my environment setup to do the actual programming.

This is a DBus backend application that will use GIO to connect to DBus.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I try to compile:

```
~$ gcc main.c
main.c:2:21: fatal error: gio/gio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gio/gio.h>
```

I believe that I've installed the correct packages as indicated [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DeveloperTools/Installation/Fedora), and gio.h exists at `/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h`.

I found a command online to add a search directory to gcc, but that resulted in other errors:

```
~$ gcc -I /usr/include/glib-2.0/ main.c 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:28,
                 from main.c:2:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:34:24: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glibconfig.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

There has to be some relatively simple method for being able to set some options/variables (makefile?) to automatically include the necessary headers. I'm also going to use Eclipse-CDT or Anjuta as an IDE and would appreciate help to fix the import path (or whatever it's called in C).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile a simple program on ubuntu arm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877528/compile-a-simple-program-on-ubuntu-arm) which first answer fits this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pkg-config` (and `make`). See exactly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18877584/841108) to a very similar question. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585574/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) answers. Don't forget `-Wall -g` flags to `gcc` ..

<sup>You don't need an IDE to compile your code (the IDE will just run some `gcc` commands, so better know how to use them yourself).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works `gcc -Wall -g main.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0) -o main`. I'll have to learn make, but this will at least get me started.